# How to perform stratification based on a column in Snowflake

Tags: sql, r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using Snowflake to write my sql queries. We have a huge table with billions of records containing customer information. The goal is to get random sample out and use R to look at the distributions. Unfortunately, we can't use JDBC/ODBC connection from RStudio to the Database. It is a limitation. So I am left with pulling extract from Snowflake and importing into R.

The difficulty, is we have a column called **CUSTOMER SEGMENT** which has almost 24 unique values. The goal is to get a sample which represents significant proportion from each segment. I tried the following query;

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM test sample(10)
```

to obtain random sample where each row has 10 percent probability of being selected. But I am not obtaining sample from each values of customer segment. May I know of any sql commands, which can help to stratify based on Customer segment. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative way of sampling for more *equal-sized* partitions is to use round robin sampling

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by segment order by random()) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from test t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 20;
```

The "20" says up to 20 rows for each segment.

This can be modified for a percentage based sample.  It is not clear if that is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.May I know how can we modify to get percentage based sample for each segment. Apologies if it was not clarified earlier.

Comment: for example if segment A has 30 percent of data, segment B has 15 percent, then I would like  to have same representation in the random sample too. can you kindly advise how to obtain that?

Comment: @Jayant . . . A random sample should do well-enough in that circumstance.  Do you require exact stratification?  If so, your question is not clear on that point.

Comment: good to know that stratification with respect to customer segment can be done. Is there a way to implement it in Snowflake?kindly advise

Answer (score 1):

For some large number of rows, this will approach a stratified sample.

```
select     *
from       test
order by   row_number() over (partition by segment_1, segment_2 order by random()) /
           count(*) over (partition by segment_1, segment_2)
limit      1000000
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of stratification in Snowflake (or SQL), based on the following:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling

This can be returned as a fixed number or percentage.

This has been complied as a single query, in our implementation we actually pre-created the sorted segment column table (W0) as a temp table instead of having the same query run mulitple times.

```
SELECT 
    W1.Id, 
    W1.EmploymentStatus,    
    W1.Gender
    FROM 
        ( SELECT 
            ID, 
            Row_Number() OVER ( PARTITION BY COALESCE(Gender, '') || COALESCE(EmploymentStatus,'') ORDER BY random() ) as iInternalRank, 
            COALESCE(Gender, '') || COALESCE(EmploymentStatus,'') as sInternalGroupVal 
            FROM STAFF ) W0,
        STAFF W1    -- Linked back the original table (Inbound query)
    WHERE (
            SELECT 
                    MAX(case when W2.sInternalGroupVal = W3.sInternalGroupVal then W3.iGroupSegmentVolume else 0 end ) -- This is where the magic happens...
                    FROM ( 
                            SELECT 
                                ID, 
                                Row_Number() OVER ( PARTITION BY COALESCE(Gender, '') || COALESCE(EmploymentStatus,'') ORDER BY random() ) as iInternalRank, 
                                COALESCE(Gender, '') || COALESCE(EmploymentStatus,'') as sInternalGroupVal 
                                FROM STAFF ) W2, 
                        (SELECT 
                            sInternalGroupVal, 
                            COUNT(Id)*(40/iTotalPopulation::DOUBLE PRECISION) as iGroupSegmentVolume -- as a fixed volumne (40 Records)
                            --COUNT(Id)*((iTotalPopulation*(23/100.00))/iTotalPopulation::DOUBLE PRECISION) as iGroupSegmentVolume -- as a percentage (23% of overall population)
                            FROM (SELECT 
                                    ID, 
                                    Row_Number() OVER ( PARTITION BY COALESCE(Gender, '') || COALESCE(EmploymentStatus,'') ORDER BY random() ) as iInternalRank, 
                                    COALESCE(Gender, '') || COALESCE(EmploymentStatus,'') as sInternalGroupVal 
                                    FROM STAFF ), 
                                 (SELECT 
                                    COUNT(Id) as iTotalPopulation 
                                    FROM ( SELECT 
                                            ID, 
                                            Row_Number() OVER ( PARTITION BY COALESCE(Gender, '') || COALESCE(EmploymentStatus,'') ORDER BY random() ) as iInternalRank, 
                                            COALESCE(Gender, '') || COALESCE(EmploymentStatus,'') as sInternalGroupVal 
                                            FROM STAFF )
                                         ) W4
                            GROUP BY sInternalGroupVal, iTotalPopulation) W3
                    WHERE ((W2.sInternalGroupVal = W0.sInternalGroupVal)) AND ((W2.sInternalGroupVal = W3.sInternalGroupVal))
            ) >= iInternalRank 
            AND ((W1.Id = W0.Id));
```